# How to Override InputFormat and OutputFormat In hadoop Application

Tags: java, hadoop, io

I have an application which need to read a file which is a serialized result of ArrayList.(`ArrayList<String>`, 50000 records in this list, size: 20MB)
I don't know exactly how to read the data in to hadoop platform. I only have some sense I need to override InputFormat and OutpurFormat.
I'm a beginner in hadoop platform. Could you give me some advise?

Thanks,

Zheng.

Comment: Could you add some details? Is your application a map/reduce job? If it is, why do you need to process only 20MB on hadoop or each item of array is params for heavy calculation you want to do on the cluster. May be want just to read data from HDFS?

Comment: 20MB is just a test file. The final experiment would be as large as 200GB so I use Hadoop platform. I have this 20MB file on my linux server. This server also installs hadoop. I want to write a job to process this file. I know how to write mapper and reducer. But I don't know exactly how to read the file for mapper class to process. I have put the file into HDFS using `hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal /home/me/test.byte /home/test/test.byte`. Could you give me some advise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start with you'll need to extend the FileInputFormat, notable implementing the abstract [FileInputFormat.createRecordReader](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.3/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/InputFormat.html#createRecordReader%28org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputSplit,%20org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskAttemptContext%29) method.

You can look through the source of something like the [LineRecordReader](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/hadoop/common/tags/release-1.0.3/src/mapred/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/LineRecordReader.java?view=markup) (which is what [TextInputFormat](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/hadoop/common/tags/release-1.0.3/src/mapred/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/TextInputFormat.java?view=markup) uses to process text files).

From there you're pretty much on your own (i.e. it depends on how your ArrayList has been serialized). Look through the source for the LineRecordReader and try and relate that to how your ArrayList has been serialized.

Some other points of note, is your file format splittable? I.e. can you seek to an offset in the file and recover the stream from there (Text files can as they just scan forward to the end of the current line and then start from there). If your file format uses compression, you also need to take this into account (you cannot for example randomly seek to a position in a gzip file). By default FileInputFormat.isSplittable will return true, which you may want to initially override to be false. If you do stick with 'unsplittable' then note that your file will be processed by a single mapper (not matter it's size).

Answer (score 0):

Before processing data on Hadoop you should upload data to HDFS or another supported file system of cause if it wasn't upload here by something else. If you are controlling the uploading process you can convert data on the uploading stage to something you can easily process, like:

- simple text file (line per array's item)
- SequenceFile if array can contain lines with '\n'

This is the simplest solution since you don't have to interfere to Hadoop's internals.